# React Native - set State nested object doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to set state a nested object and I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43041334/8943429), but I don't know everytime I `setState` following the answer, the state still not set

Here's my code I've tried:

```
// declare the state
constructor(props){
  super(props); 
  this.state = {
    bius: {name:'bius', time:0, status:false},
  }
}

// Function to setstate
_timer(name){
    // this.setState({[name]: !this.state.name})
  var upd = {...this.state[name]}
  upd.status = !upd.status
  console.log(upd.status)
  console.log(this.state.bius)
  this.setState({upd})
  console.log("setstate upd")
  console.log(upd)
  console.log(this.state.bius)
}

// here I call the function to set state
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{this._timer('bius')}}>
  <Text style={[global.global.SubHeaderText, {color:'white'}]}>Start</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and here is output of log :

```
I/ReactNativeJS(6694): true
I/ReactNativeJS(6694): { name: 'bius', time: 0, status: false }
I/ReactNativeJS(6694): setstate upd
I/ReactNativeJS(6694): { name: 'bius', time: 0, status: true }
I/ReactNativeJS(6694): { name: 'bius', time: 0, status: false }
```

I don't know why the `upd.status` already `true`, but the `this.state.bius.status` still `false`?

why `this.state.bius.status` not set to `true`?

Comment: I think you have to bind the _timer function tonthe compinent because it doesnt know about the state. Rewrite it to es6 ‘func _timer = (name) => {}’ or in constructor ‘this._timer.bind(this._timer)’

Comment: Shouldn't the this.setState(...) be outside the _timer function?

Comment: @parohy still no luck, your 1st suggest giving me the same output, and your 2nd suggest makes my function not running well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the event. Read [this react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

You also need to use the [spread operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) here and only change the key you wish too

```
this._timer.bind(this,'bius');
//..

this.setState(prevState => ({ 
   bius: {
      ...prevState.bius,
      status: !prevState.bius.status
}));
```

Also you `upd.status = !upd.status;` won't work as the state has not changed. You need to call setState there too. And another thing as mentioned in a comment on your question. You should use arrow functions if you are not going to bind the event handler.

Comment: I tried your code, but the App not detected `status` as variable

Comment: might need `status: !prevState.status`

Comment: Let me know how it goes

Comment: as you see about the `onPress` event at my code, I'm using `{()=>{this._timer('bius')}}` so the bind is unused, but still the console.log showing the same output as i declare, is `...prevState.bius` is good to implement?

Comment: o.O oops `status: !prevState.bius.status`

Answer (score 1):

setState is async function. So, if you want to print your state, you should console.log() on call back. For example:

```
this.setState({bius: {name:'example'}},()=>{console.log(this.state)})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState() updates the state  asynchronously. That is why you do not see in console log. To get the log correctly add a console.log in render function as below .

export default class app extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bius: { name: 'bius', time: 0, status: false },
    }
  }

  // Function to setstate
  _timer(name) {
    var upd = { ...this.state[name] }
    upd.status = !upd.status
    this.setState({ bius: upd })
  }


  render() {
    console.log("MYLOG", this.state.bius)
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 100 }} onPress={() => { this._timer('bius') }}>
        <Text >Start</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to mistake i `this.setState({upd})`

You can do another way `this.setState({bius:upd})`
Try this one let me know whats happened.

Comment: You can check yor state update or not in call back 

this.setState({bius:upd},()=>{
Console.log(this.state.bius);
})

Check this i have sure you get updated state in call back.

Comment: the console.log seems doesn't appear, what happened -_-